# Deserialization of OData objects to Java objects with Apache Olingo

Tags: java, client, odata, olingo

We need to integrate a OData service within a Java application. Due to lack of documentation for [SDL/Odata](https://github.com/sdl/odata) we decided to use Apache Olingo.

Our use case is to only query/ read objects from a given service (we will never write).

My question is: How to deserialize the received data to real objects?
Is there a way (Odata 4) to use annotated classes (like Jpa or Json/Jackson) to deserialize directly into a class?

The examples i found are using no specific classes and use String literals to declare field names. Is this the only way? Is there an example that at least has specific data classes per entity delivered by odata?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a JPAProcessor for Olingo 4. There is one available here [olingo-jpa-processor-v4](https://github.com/SAP/olingo-jpa-processor-v4)

Unfortunately it also is lacking documentation and is pre-release

Comment: but what is the proposed way to do this with olingo?